# How to maintain visible what was captured after user interacts with site with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning Javascript by my own using CodeAcademy.
I would like to know how I could maintain the user interaction. Attached is my To DO list. It works well when the site is up, but if I refresh the browser, the user interaction is lost and the whole code starts over without the data that the user input. I would like to show what the interaction the user left.
Will I need another thing I need to learn, such as database or another program?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
        if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'list') {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('.done');
        } else {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('.list');
        }

    });

});
```

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:70px;
    background-color:#cc0000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}
.list {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc0000;
}
.done {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>To Do</h2>

<form name="checkListForm">
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
<h2>Done:</h2>
<div class="done"></div>
```

query and javaScript that I need to learn to do that? Like database?

Comment: In real world applications you would store the information in some sort of database. In your case a quick way would be is to set a cookie with the information that you want to save.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Each time you append to `list`, update `localStorage` with its HTML contents:

```
localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify($('.list').html()));
```

When you load the program, fill `list` with what's in `localStorage`:

```
$('.list').html(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list')));
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bfn4tub9/).

Each time you reload it, it remembers what you last added.

Note that this works on a single computer only.  You'll need a server database solution if you want to access your to-do list on different computers.